# jupyter lab is broken how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, jupyter-lab

I can't figure out why jupyter-lab is not working. something is broken and don't know where. I have searched the web for this and can't find a solution. COuld you please help. Appreciate it.

E:\gitrepos>jupyter lab

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import jupyterlab.labapp
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import NotebookApp, aliases, flags
  File "C:\Users\Dario.Romero\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 78, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager
  File "C:\Users\Dario.Romero\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 61, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.jsonutil import extract_dates, squash_dates, date_default
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\jsonutil.py", line 11, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse as _dateutil_parse
ImportError: No module named 'dateutil.parser'`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `dateutil` library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/

(If you used a package manager, the dependencies for JupyterLab should already have been installed. If you didn't, then you will need to install the dependencies yourself.)